# « C'est assez discuté » et expressions similaires : grammaire

Tags: grammaire, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

[c'est assez discuté](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22c%27est%20assez%20discut%C3%A9%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)

Il s'agit d'une famille de tournures puisqu'on trouve aussi [c'est assez parlé](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22c%27est%20assez%20parl%C3%A9%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr), d'ailleurs plus souvent.

Les construction avec « c'est assez » n'autorisent pas un participe passé selon le ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/assez)).

On utilise  l'auxiliaire « avoir » avec « discuter », et de toute façon « ça a assez discuté » ne correspond pas : ça ne peut être employé que dans de rares cas.

Comment analyser ces formes ?  Principe grammatical ou expressions figées ? Je ne vois que cette dernière solution mais sait-on jamais.

(Le sens est « c'est assez de discussions ».)

Comment: « Les construction avec « c'est assez » n'autorisent pas un participe passé. » ?????? Assez [dans le dictionnaire de l'Académie](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9A2835) (1.4). Si même l'Académie Française « l'autorise » !

Comment: @None Il n'y a pas d'explication dans le TLFi. L'académie donne quelque chose en plus : « C’est assez disputé. », mais aucune explication. Tout ça c'est très bien, mais on s'intéresse à la grammaire ici, c'est une question de grammaire. Pourquoi ce vote négatif ? C'est bien à vous que je dois ce vote négatif et vous le justifier par quoi ? Vous jouez sur un petit mot qui manque, (selon le TLFi) ?

Comment: Ah ! Je  n'ai pas été clair(e), j'ai cité l'affirmation qui m'avait fait réagir. La question contient une affirmation faite de façon péremptoire, sans citation,  justification, etc., pour moi la question a été posée sans recherche préalable.  Inutile : risque de mise en erreur  de quelqu'un qui ferait confiance à ce qui est écrit de façon aussi assurée. Explication claire sur le site de l'Académie : « Sert à exprimer que la mesure est comble ».  C'est une tournure certes un peu désuète (le dic. de l'Académie donne *c'est assez parlé* dès sa première édition) mais encore vivante de nos jours.

Comment: @None Ce que ça signifie n'est pas le sujet de la question, je connais ces expressions, et leur sens. C'est leur statu grammatical que la question aborde.

Comment: « L'académie donne quelque chose en plus : « C’est assez disputé. », mais aucune explication. » « aucune explication », suivi de rien. je disais que si, il y en a une.

Comment: 1) **C'est assez discuté** puisqu'effectivement, on peut avoir une atteinte systémique qui débute par un organe et cela a peu d'intérêt. https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/p_3341435/en/nucala-06042022-transcription-19631 2) **C'est assez discuté** pour une telle babiole, je ne cherche pas à contrarier Claire, mais je ne peux sacrifier une rose que je ne connais pas, pour un caprice. Expliquez-lui que c'est impossible. https://www.paperblog.fr/2324646/la-rose/

Answer (score 2):

Les expressions avec *c'est assez* autorisent bel et bien un participe passé (c'est tout simplement une tournure passive dans de nombreux cas, mais pas tous) et sont assez courantes.

Deux sens possibles (au moins?) pour *c'est assez discuté*:

1. un sujet de conversation, qui sera dans le contexte, est discuté par de nombreuses personnes, il y a controverse - il s'agit ici d'une **litote** ou d'un **euphémisme**;
2. il n'est plus nécessaire de discuter, celui/celle qui dit *c'est assez discuté* veut mettre un terme à la discussion, le sujet a été *suffisamment* discuté.

Autres expressions courantes avec *c'est assez* (attention, les nuances peuvent varier suivant les expressions): *c'est assez disputé*, *c'est assez pensé*, *c'est assez vérifié*, *c'est assez tergiversé*, *c'est assez réfléchi*, *c'est assez employé*, *c'est assez déterminé*, *c'est assez répandu*, *c'est assez dormi* ... et bien d'autres.

On trouve par exemple chez Molière (*Le Médecin malgré lui*, acte I, scène 5, 1666):

> Sganarelle. *– La, la, la… Ma foi, c'est assez travaillé pour boire un coup ; prenons un peu d'haleine.*

Comme pour *c'est assez discuté*, l'expression *c'est assez travaillé* peut avoir plusieurs sens, par exemple, que Sganarelle estime qu'il a *suffisamment* travaillé et peut donc prendre une pause, ou bien, dans un autre contexte, *c'est assez travaillé* pourrait signifier que quelque chose a été suffisamment élaboré, ou recherché, ou fait preuve d'un certain travail qui a produit un résultat remarquable.

Merci @Marck, @None et @jiliagre pour les suggestions, corrections et compléments.

Comment: Oui, et d'ailleurs on dit même plus souvent "C'est assez !" ou "Assez !" pour signifier qu'on en a marre de parler d'un sujet !

Comment: @Marck Tu aurais d'autres exemples pour ma liste? J'ai l'impression d'avoir tapé un peu toujours dans les mêmes.

Comment: Laquelle : celle des sens possibles ou celle des expressions ?

Comment: C'est assez dormi bande de marmottes !

Comment: @Marck Les 2? Pour les sens possibles, il y aurait aussi _c'est assez de discussion_, qui revient un peu à 2. Tu vois d'autres sens? Pour les expressions, je suis preneur, oui - ceci dit, pas la peine d'en faire une list de 10 pages de long...

Comment: Vous osez fournir une réponse après avoir mis un vote négatif à ma question ? Vous trouvez ça très fin ?

Comment: @Frank "C'est assez discuté." (comprendre "Tel sujet est assez discuté.") peut aussi être une **litote** pour signifier que le sujet en question est beaucoup discuté. Dans la grande majorité des cas, *assez* signifie "une quantité suffisante" et peut donc être substitué par *suffisamment*. Exemples : *J'ai assez mangé.* (signifiant "J'ai suffisamment mangé, je n'ai plus faim") ; *J'en ai fait assez.* ("J'ai terminé la quantité de travail qui m'était dûe, voire plus.") ; *En ce moment, la guerre est assez violente.* ("En ce moment, la guerre est plus violente que d'habitude.") [LITOTE] ; etc.

Comment: @Marck Merci! J'ai coupé/collé un bout de ton commentaire avec attribution, j'espère que ça te convient?

Comment: Le passif ne marche pas avec tout,  *c'est assez dormi* (→*vous avez assez dormi*) où vois-tu le passif ? Par ailleurs, pas d'accord pour *c'est assez limité*, là je ne vois que l'adjectif, pas le pp. idem avec d'autres de ta liste : établi, perdu.

Comment: @None Oui, tu as raison, ce n'est pas toujours un passif, même si parfois c'est le cas, ou si ça y ressemble. J'enlève _c'est assez limité_ et autres.

Comment: @None _C'est assez discuté_, dans un sens, pourrait être: _ce sujet est suffisamment discuté_, qui me semble être à la voix passive?

Comment: @Frank oui merci ! Seulement (et pardon, je me suis probablement mal exprimé), il faut séparer *la partie avec "suffisamment"*, et la mettre sur ton **deuxième point** qui dit qu'*"il n'est plus nécessaire de discuter"* ! D'ailleurs tu peux également rajouter dans le point 3. que c'est une litote ou un **euphémisme**

Comment: @Marck ok, merci, je corrige.

Comment: @Marck, en fait, je crois que la litote/euphémisme est mon premier point? J'avais mis "controverse" pour aller dans ce sens - qu'en penses-tu?

Comment: Avec discuté pas de pb.

Comment: J'ai transformé en "community wiki" si vous avez d'autres choses à ajouter.

Comment: @Frank au temps pour moi, je n'avais pas bien compris ton point 1. ! En effet, ça me semble correct

Answer (score 1):

Le TLFi est un grand dictionnaire mais pas une grammaire et ses choix lexicographiques de syntagmes, tournures ou locutions ne sont ni exhaustifs ni déterminants. Si une question faisait de ses choix une affirmation péremptoire elle serait frivole alors que dire d'une question qui ferait une prémisse par extrusion de son absence de présentation ? Rien ne détaille entièrement la langue sauf l'entièreté de son usage.

Ceci dit, une manière de relier la tournure à un choix de présentation de la grammaire est de l'associer au contexte de l'infinitif attribut sans préposition (*vouloir, c'est pouvoir*). Et éventuellement à la concurrence entre l'infinitif et le participe passé dans une variété de ce contexte où le pronom peut représenter autre chose qu'un infinitif tout en pouvant ordinairement être remplacé par un infinitif (Le propos paraphrase de très près *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup> § 913 a R3). Avec un adverbe, « C'est assez PARLER de cet homme » (Green, cit. au LBU) :

> Dans ce cas-là, l'infinitif est concurrencé par le participe passé :
> *C'était chouettement RÉPONDU. — Six ans d'exil* [...] *était-ce si cher
> PAYÉ* [...] ? (POIROT-DELPECH, dans le *Monde*, 20 mai 1977.) - [L'Ac.
> 1932](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A8A2095) donnait côte à côte, s. v. *assez*, *C'est assez parlé, assez
> disputé* et *C'est assez PARLER, assez DISPUTER*; en 2001, elle se
> contente de *C'est assez DISPUTÉ*, ce qui est regrettable. —
> L'hésitation existe aussi dans des phrases sans verbe conjugué : *Mais
> assez PARLER de moi...* (GIDE, *Faux-monn.*, III, 7.) — *J'ai raison et
> vous le savez. Assez DISCUTÉ* (FARRÈRE, cit. Sandfeld, t. III, § 43).
>
> [ *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup> §
> 913 note R3 verbatim ]

Il s'agit encore une fois d'un phénomène où il y a hésitation et concurrence. Où il y a nuance, abstraction, pragmatisme et aucun couperet qui ne tombe sur un pan de la langue...

Comment: +1 En fait, si je voulais vraiment, je pourrais même utiliser _c'est asser parler de cette homme_ et _c'est assez parlé de cet homme_ avec une petite nuance: l'infinitif est plus proche d'une abstraction ("_c'est assez parler de cet homme que de dire qu'il était marin_", mais on n'a pas eu de discussion à ce sujet) alors que le pp évoquerait plutôt la clôture d'une discussion qui a eu lieu. Mais je ne dis pas qu'il y a forcèment une énorme différence - bel et bien _hésitation et concurrence_.